# 3 plm-package (R) questions

Tags: r, multiple-regression, panel-data, random-effects-model, plm

I am currently trying to perform my panel data analysis with R using the package 'plm'. This has resulted in 3 questions for me:

**(1)** Since the panel analysis with 'plm' is still a linear regression, the requirements have to be checked. Especially for the linearity requirements the Ramsey-Reset-Test can be used. However, I have not found a corresponding counterpart for 'plm' so far. Would it still be correct as a procedure to perform the reset test for each year to take the panel structure into account? Or is there any other way (except graphically) to check the linearity using 'plm'?

**(2)** Influential observations and outliers can have a great influence on the results in linear regression. As far as I have understood the documentation correctly, influential cases can be considered by type="HC3" or "HC4". Does this procedure make it unnecessary to analyze influential observations? How can I determine outliers in R especially in my panel model e.g. at the 1% level?

**(3)** I would like to calculate several models (pooled, fixed, random) in 'plm'. If I use 'summary' for a random effects model, I only get 'chisq' with z-values but no F-Statistic (t-values). Using robust standard errors by 'coeftest' I get t-values. Accordingly, my reporting of t-values (robust standard errors) would not match the Chi²-statistic, since 'coeftest' does not give me F-statistics and R/R² output. However, since I have already seen outputs of the F-statistics in random effects models using the 'Swamy-Arora's transformation', I am surprised that a Chi² distribution is calculated for me. Can this be changed?

I hope that these questions are justified, since I don't have much experience with data analysis especially in R.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is little use in "testing" for distributional assumptions for models. Any test almost necessarily requires inspecting a more general, flexible model which begs the question: if you can fit a more general, flexible model, what are you doing try to interpret the simple model? Why squeeze a square peg through a round hole? Diagnostic *plots* on the other hand are more useful... and probably warrant a different question.
2. Influential observations may arise due to a. bad luck b. non-normal but IID error distributions c. model misspecification, or d. heteroscedasticity. Without getting into too much detail, "HC0" and its variants will generally handle case d only if no further action is taken on your part.
3. If you are using "HC0" or its variants for robust standard error estimates, you would not expect to have $F$ or $T$ statistics for inference on fixed effects. This is because the heteroscedasticity consistent (HC) or *sandwich* variance estimator is an asymptotic variance estimator. If you truly believe that your errors are normally distributed and that the model is correctly specified (which I don't think you do), you would have to use model-based error estimates and you should get these tests. Even this I cannot guarantee, since inference on fixed effects in the general class of "panel models" may still rely on asymptotic theory for most tests.

Comment: Many thanks for this quick answer.

(1) Most of my independent variables have a linear relationship to the dependent variable via plot. A few variables, however, have a broad scatter plot. But there are no other clear connections, e.g. quadratic recognizable. A transformation e.g. by logarithmizing, Sqrt ...  did not bring any improvement, so my intention was to verify again with the Ramsey-Reset-Test.

Should I rather deduce from these broad scattering plots that the linear specification is unsuitable or an check with the Ramsey reset test (year-based) be the right approach?

Comment: 2) I applied the Shapiro-Wilk test and the Jarque-Bera test to my random effects model and normally distributed residuals were found. Precisely because the condition of heteroscedascity is violated, I have used the robust estimator (I have no autocorrection, multicollinearity). 

Are other actions from my side necessary to verify influential observations and outliers? What other actions could I choose?

Comment: (3) Since the Hausman test meets the requirements for using a random effects model (RE-model), I tend to use this model. A fixed effects model is actually out of question for me because of time invariant variables. 

What exactly do you mean by 'model-based error estimitates'? I thought that due to the violation of the heteroscedascicity condition I would estimate a robust standard error estimator for my RE-model.

Comment: I implemented this as follows:

`random<-plm(y~x1+x2+..., data = panel, model = "random", index = c("id", "year"))
coeftest(random, vcov=vcovHC, method="white1", type="HC4")`

Is this approach not valid? Nevertheless, I have the problem that the output of the RE-model's 'summary' with Chi² does not match the estimation of the standard errors of the 'coeftest'? In this case, would you still report t-values with the significances of the independent variables and the Chi²-value of the entire model (without F-statistics)?

Comment: ad (3): for random effect models, the precise distribution of estimates is not known which is why you get z- and Chi^2-values for random effect models in any case. For the models you get t- and F-Values unless you specify heteroskadestic/autocorrelared consistent standard errors. This automatic switch is the typical approach of any software I know. `lmtest::coeftest` is likely not aware of the specifc `plm` model type which is why it does not switch automatically but the user the assumed to know what he/she does (as should be the case for anything at anytime).